# Looping through a HTML list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do I loop through a list of `li` tags inside a `ul` in order to get the `textContent` of the clicked `li` element?

```
var ul    = document.getElementsByClassName('ul')[0];
var items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

$("li").on("click", function(){
    for (var i =0; i<items.length;i++) {
        console.log(items[i]);
    }
});
```

My attempt above logs the `textContent` of all the `li` elements within the list whereas I only want the `textContent` of the clicked element. How could I specify the element clicked?

Comment: `$("li").on("click", function(){console.log($(this).text());});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(e){
   console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kiluminati's answer should do the trick.
This is how it works:

- `$('ul > li')` creates an array of jQuery object made of all the `li`s
- The jQuery method `.on()` attaches an eventListener to the DOM object, in this case, each `li` element
- When the element is clicked, the eventListener is triggered, and calls the handler function, binding its `this` variable context to the element that was clicked

Comment: Brilliantly explained, Thanks!